# rails belongs_to customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I read in some code this

```
attr_accessible :namespace_id, :creator_id, as: :admin
belongs_to :creator,      foreign_key: "creator_id", class_name: "User"
```

Why not simply declare a `user_id` in the model (and in table), and then simply use `belongs_to :user` ? Btw, is now `creator` an alias to `creator_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `user` is semantically meaningless, while `creator` is not.

As an example lets assume I have two models called a `Book` and `Person`. I can set up an association to a book's author in the `people` table, and it will be an instance of `Person`.  I can call the association "person", simply because that matches the name of the model, or call it "author". Which one more accurately conveys the relationship between models?

Comment: No. `creator_id` is the foreign key; it's an integer. `creator` is an instantiated model, an instance of the `User` class. They are not aliases for each other, though they are related.